# Pagination with Codeigniter - Not counting or returning records

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm having a problem with pagination not counting the amount of records and not creating links correctly.

My code is here -> http://pastie.org/8506894

Everything is within the function.

It shows up the links but it's not limiting to the specific $limit I set.

Really could do with some help on this please.   :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Limit and Limit Offset in your query for number of rows you would like returned by the query.

like this:

```
$this->db->limit($pagination_start, $pagination_length);
```

where First param is the Length and second is the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to take into account a limit and offset. That's the only way it is going to be able to respect the limit you set in your configuration.

I would add the following changes:

```
public function list_all($page = 1)
```

After initiating the method:

```
$limit = 15;
if ($page == 0) {
    $offset = 0;
} else {
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
}
```

Now we have a proper limit and offset. To make things display correctly you should also add this to your pagination configuration:

```
$config["per_page"] = $limit;
$config["use_page_numbers"] = TRUE;
```

Lastly, you need to add to your query:

```
$this->db->limit($offset, $limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the controller you must to set type number of parameters on url

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 2; // or 3 if you have 3
```

it will be work